# Skip two lines if a match is found in sed

Tags: linux, text-processing, sed

I am trying to clear up a text file using `sed`.

I have a program that runs pings and outputs to a text file. 
In the program I have added a time stamp after the ping output
so I know when it failed.

I need to remove all except for when the ping failed, and the two lines below and one above. 
Is there any way to skip the next two lines if my `sed` expression is met?

Example:

```
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 18.001/21.159/26.006/2.959 ms
Tue 26 Nov 09:39:56 GMT 2019


--- 4.2.2.2 ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 9 received, 10% packet loss, time 18034ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 20.560/34.013/70.076/17.428 ms
Tue 26 Nov 09:40:46 GMT 2019

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 17.510/20.543/26.618/2.317 ms
Tue 26 Nov 09:41:04 GMT 2019
```

If I use the following:  `sed '/loss/!d' pingFailed.txt > pingFailed1.txt`

then my output looks like this:

```
10 packets transmitted, 4 received, 60% packet loss, time 18103ms
10 packets transmitted, 3 received, 70% packet loss, time 18107ms
```

but I need my output to look like this:

```
--- 4.2.2.2 ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 9 received, 10% packet loss, time 18034ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 20.560/34.013/70.076/17.428 ms
Tue 26 Nov 09:40:46 GMT 2019
```

How can I do it (preferably in `sed`)?

Answer (score 3):

Tell me if this suits you:

```
grep -B1 -A2 "loss" pingFailed.txt > pingFailed1.txt
```

Output:

```
--- 4.2.2.2 ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 9 received, 10% packet loss, time 18034ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 20.560/34.013/70.076/17.428 ms
Tue 26 Nov 09:40:46 GMT 2019
```

---

Find the line with the pattern "loss":

```
grep "loss"
```

Print one line **B**efore:

```
-B1
```

Print two lines **A**fter:

```
-A2
```

Comment: Hi Yes this works perfectly.  

As i am a Linux Noob please can you just explain it to me ThankYou Again

Comment: @Mohammed I edited the question, the explanation is simple. If in doubt, write me again.

Comment: Thankyou for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

To do it with `sed`:

```
sed -n '/loss/ { x; G; N; N; p; s/.*// }; x' pingFailed.txt > pingFailed1.txt
```

Explanation:

- `-n`: Don’t print anything automatically;
  print only when there’s a **p**rint command.
- `/loss/ { … }`: Do the commands inside the braces
  when you see a line containing “`loss`”.
- `x`: Swap the pattern space and the hold space. 
  The pattern space contains the line we just read. 
  Spoiler alert: the hold space contains the previous line. 
  After this command, the pattern space contains the previous line
  and the hold space contains the current line.
- `G`: Get the contents of the hold space
  and append it the pattern space (inserting a newline between them). 
  After this command, the pattern space contains the previous line
  followed by the current line (i.e., the `loss` line and the line before it).
- `N`: Read another line from the input
  and append it to the pattern space (inserting a newline between them).
- `p`: Print the pattern space,
  which, at this point, contains the `loss` line,
  the line before it and the two lines after it.
- `s/.*//`: Clear out the pattern space.
- `x`: Swap the pattern space and the hold space. 
  Note that this command is executed whether `loss` is matched or not.

  - If `loss` was matched,
    we just did all the commands inside the `{` … `}` braces (listed above),
    so the pattern space is blank. 
    So this sets the hold space to blank.
    (I’m not sure that this is *really* necessary, but it’s probably a good idea.)
  - If `loss` was not matched, the pattern space contains the current line;
    so this puts the current line into the hold space.

As far as I can tell, this works perfectly if the input is as you describe.

- If the first line of the input contains `loss`,
  then this will print a blank line and the first three lines of the input
  (i.e., the `loss` line and the two lines after it).
- If the last or second-to-last line of the input contains `loss`,
  then this will not print it,
  because there aren’t two lines after the `loss` line
  — because `sed` aborts the command sequence
  when it encounters the end of file. 
  If you want to handle this case by printing the `loss` line,
  the line before it, and the (single) line after it (if any), do this:

  ```
  sed -n '/loss/ { x; G; p; n; p; n; p; s/.*// }; x' pingFailed.txt > pingFailed1.txt
  ```

  to read and print the two “after” lines individually.